# osx complains that app is from unidentified developer, although it passes all validations

Tags: macos, code-signing, macos-sierra

I have developer certificate (bought it from apple 99$ per year) , signed my application with xcode

[image: code signing parameters]

here also output from spctl

```
spctl  --assess -v /Volumes/<valume>/myapp.app
/Volumes/<valume>/myapp.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
```

I have check also my application via RB app checker light
all seems ok , app checker can see that app is signed.
but when I creatin dmg which contains my app, uploading it to our server, 
the downloaded app cant be opened, because osx complains that app is from unidentified developer. I'm out of ideas what the reason could be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should check this technical note:

[TN2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG18)

However, I will summarize in a few lines a few checks that you need to make to ensure that everything goes OK:

a) Make sure you are using the **latest Xcode version** — sometimes just upgrading can solve all your problems

b) Make sure Xcode is set to **manage automatically your certificate and provisioning profiles** — this is probably the best advice I can give you if you have problems in code signing. In summary, if you have Xcode 8, you have to:

1. Click on your **project** in the navigation area (on the left) > **Build Settings** tab.
2. Set the **Provisioning Profile** build setting to **Automatic** for all build
   configurations.
3. Set the **Code Signing Identity** build setting:

   - Set to **iOS Developer** for all build configurations in iOS projects.
   - Set to **Mac Developer** or **Developer ID**, as appropriate, for all build configurations in macOS projects.
4. Set your target in Targets > General > Team to **None**
5. For Mac apps, set your target in Targets > General > Signing to **None.**
6. Change the **Provisioning Profile** build setting to **Automatic** for all build configurations.
7. Set the **Code Signing Identity** build setting:

   - Set to **iOS Developer** for all build configurations in iOS targets.
   - Set to **Mac Developer** or **Developer ID**, as appropriate, for all build configurations in macOS targets.
8. Go back to Targets and revert General > Team > to your team and
9. Check **Automatically manage signing** checkbox
10. Restart Xcode.

This is in part explained in the [QA1814](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1814/_index.html), but some important steps are missing in it and some information in it is outdated. So I advise that you do what I say above.

c) If you are running on El Capitan (10.11) or later, check your code by running the following commands in Terminal:

```
$ spctl -a -v path/to/your.app
```

It should yield something like:

```
path/to/your.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
```

Another command that you should check is:

```
$ spctl -a -v --raw path/to/your.app
```

or this:

```
$ codesign --verbose=4 --deep --strict path/to/your.app
```

These will check if any the frameworks or any embedded code is doing something that is not supposed to, such as pointing to code outside of the allowed directories such as:

```
/System
/Library
/usr
```

as that poses a security risk.

However, do not use the latter command to really code sign your app. This is only to mimic what Gatekeeper does to check your app.

To know more what command you should use, read the [Code Signing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html).

d) code sign your dmg disk image by using the command:

```
codesign -s <identity> <disk-image>
```

This is now highly recommended for your software to run on macOS Sierra without any problems.

Comment: thanks for your answer @jvarela , now i have signed app and signed dmg file, but the issue still exists :(

Comment: What code signing identity did you use? You must use your  Developer ID Application identity, otherwise the code signing will fail. Moreover, have you tried to upload your dmg to another server and see if it also fails? Perhaps your server is changing your disk image somehow and that will invalidate the code signing. Stranger things have happened!

Comment: Moreover, which OS are you using? macOS Sierra or an earlier one?

Comment: thanks for your responses, but the problem was my not right usage of signing overall. I even did not created provisional profile. I will accept your answer , for your willingness to help me :)